# Swift NSFetchedResultsController ignores NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i'm debugging the following code for hours now.

For me, it looks like my NSPredicate gets simply ignored.
I've 2 entries in the core data database. Whatever predicate I set I always get back these two entries. Both have a property called `type` that is 1. Even if I set the predicate to `(type == 5)` the same 2 entries are fetched.

```
    // MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }


    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // simply ignores verything here...
    // -----------------------------------------------
    // I can use (type == 5) whereby the db only contains items with type == 1...
    // It's like the predicate is nevery used in the fetchrequest.
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(name LIKE '%Eier%')")!
    println(fetchRequest.predicate)

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Main")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

Comment: Try `cacheName: nil` (or delete the cache).

Comment: That really was it... I thought the cache is only while the app is running... thanks :)